# Android: launchMode singleTop not working if app opened from another app

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have an application, which misbehaves if started from another app (e.g. over the playstore). Instead of resuming to the already existing `Activity`, it restarts as a new instance.

What I have:

- declared every activity with `launchMode="singleTop"`in `manifest.xml`
- **I tried the same with** `launchMode=singleTask`, but it has the same behaviour
- used additional `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` on every `Intent` which starts a new `Activity`
- `onNewIntent()` is not called in already running instance

I used following code, to start my app from another app (with, and without additional `addFlag()`)

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

My Launcher-Activity is a `SplashScreenActivity`, which starts the `MainActivity`if user is logged in with the following code and gets `finished()`

```
 Intent intent = null;
 intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

What am I missing? Any recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more researches, I added following code in the `SplashScreenAvtivity:onCreate()`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isTaskRoot())
    {
        String intentAction = getIntent().getAction();
        if (getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
    //...
```

}

This dismisses SplashScreenActivity, if App is already running. This works with all `launch-modes`

Answer (score 3):

Please try using singleTask instead of singleTop for SplashScreenActivity.
As per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

"The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one."

Comment: forgot to admit, i tried `launchMode=singleTask` and `singleInstance`, but the behaviour stays the same.....

Comment: singleTask is dangerous, as it clears all activities above